# How to switch/replace two strings in code fastest way

Tags: coding-efficiency

I often need to switch places of two strings while coding. I double click the first one, cut it with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>, go to the other string string, click at the beginning of second string, <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> to paste first string, then select second string like this: my cursor is already at the start of it, so I pres SHIFT and click mouse button at the end of it, then again <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> to cut it, then go to place of the first string which can be pages away and paste it there.

I do this often and keep thinking to my self there's gotta be quicker way to do this in some editors. I use Sublime usually. But I would switch to another one for this 'feature'.

What I would like to do is:

1. Select first string by mouse double click
2. Click special command on keyboard
3. Select second string by mouse double click
4. Click special command on the keyboard

This special command should not stretch my fingers too much, so I would prefer something close to CTRL+C, but yes most of it is occupied. So my proposal is this:

2. CTRL+CC (press C two times)
3. CTRL+V (does the replace)

This seems very fast and intuitive. Are there some drawbacks?

Answer (score 0):

Don't use the mouse. You'll waste too much time.

Use CTRL + SHIFT + ARROW_RIGHT to select the first word, starting from its first character. Select the second string the same way.

To not stretch your fingers:
- don't use CTRL + C, instead use CTRL + INS
- don't use CTRL + V, instead use SHIFT + INS

Comment: This sounds like slight improvement. i didnt know about INS copy paste. I will try to rewrite my brain there.